# Unilateral Laplace transform calculation

Tags: laplace-transform

I'd like to verify that $\mathcal{L}[e^{-at}]=\frac{1}{s+a}$, $t\ge 0$.

So I calculate: $$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty} e^{-at} e^{-st} dt=\int_{0^+}^{+\infty} e^{-t(a+s)} dt = \frac{1}{-(a+s)} e^{-t(a+s)}\Big|_{0^+}^{+\infty}$$.

Now I have to distinguish three cases:

*1)* $(a+s)\gt0$: $\frac{1}{-(a+s)} e^{-t(a+s)}\Big|_{0^+}^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{a+s}$

*2)* $(a+s)=0$: impossible (because of the domain)

*3)* $(a+s)\lt0$: $\frac{1}{-(a+s)} e^{-t(a+s)}\Big|_{0^+}^{+\infty}=+\infty+\frac{1}{a+s}$

So is $\mathcal{L}[e^{-at}]=\frac{1}{s+a}$ only valid when $a+s\gt0$?

Also: since $s \in \mathbb{C}$, the whole thing has no sense (since the inequations in $\mathbb{C}$ don't make sense) ?

**EDIT**

If I write $s=a+ib=|s|e^{i\theta}=|s|(cos\theta+isin\theta) \in \mathbb{C}$, I get:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0^+}^{+\infty} e^{-at} e^{-st} dt&=\int_{0^+}^{+\infty} e^{-at} e^{-|s|(cos \theta +i sin \theta)t} dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-(a+|s|+cos \theta +i sin \theta )t}\\
&=-\frac{e^{-(a+|s|+cos \theta + i sin \theta )t}}{a+|s|+cos \theta + i sin \theta}\Big|_{0}^{+\infty}
\end{align}
$$

But here too, I have to see if $a+|s|+cos \theta + i sin \theta$ is positive or not. Do I?

Comment: Try writing $e^{s}=\cos \left ( \theta  \right )+i\sin \left ( \theta  \right )$, and then use integration by parts.

Comment: And also note that $a+s$ makes no sense when you are working in the complex domain. Something like $a+\Re (s)$, makes more sense.

Comment: Doesn't it? If I see $a $ as a complex number with $Im (a)=0$, it's legit to do $a+s $.

Comment: @Shemafied Could you check out my *EDIT*,please?

Comment: To reply to your first comment, when the imaginary part is zero, then that is only a special case of a complex number. You want to deal with this kind of things in more general terms(acknowledging that the imaginary part might be non-zero). Beware what you put in the exponent.